# Should we write automation test code if we merely write wrapper code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Normally, when I implement new features, I write corresponding automation test code. But right now we are working on a special project. I don't know if it is good practice to write automation test code. 
The project is a legacy project, which doesn't have automation test code. The functions are stable they been there for years. We do not add any new functions to it, and we probably won't in future. We need to change the UI from flex to html, so we need to change the way how we  expose APIs. We used to expose API through spring remote. Now we switch to RESTFUL APIs. In other words, we only write wrapper code. We don't write if...else.. or loops. Is it a good practice to write automation test code for the mid-tier in such case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A unit test could verify the parameters passed to the API were correctly passed on to the wrapped component.  In this case the wrapped component might be mocked.

An integration test could verify the API (facade) correctly wired the real components, and assert the expected result.